# make desktop shell application (jar!?) which could use third reference from jnlp

Tags: java, jar, jnlp

i've to make a simply java desktop application (just working by shell...) 
which use third party code distributed by jnlp...

i've downloaded `.jnlp`, and then manually all .jar specified in that.

then created a new local project, adding these reference(to downloaded .jar), and using them, and it's ok...

i would like to avoid to distribute it like a jar with these "third jars" included,
is it possible to use the "remote third jars" specified in jnpl ?!
because these referenced class could be updated (and i know that could "broke" my code, but it's difficult, more probable just little internal changes...)
(i think that security manager should not give me "access" to third party downloaded in user temp cache...)

the second idea is to make a my own .jnlp with the third party component "reference" (just an idea that should be tested...) , but i would avoid it, i've not apache maven etc etc..

thanks giacomo

Comment: Does the main application jar contain `/META-INF/maven/.../pom.xml`? If you are lucky, you can reuse maven dependencies in your own projest...

Comment: nope ...
there is a manifest.mf
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Application-Name: Sogei Application
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 2.4 (IBM Corporation)
Codebase: *